# Why don't keyboard shortcuts work in Google Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using lots of Google tools and most of them have keyboard shortcuts -- but none of them work on Google Chrome. When I press keys (in Gmail, in Google Reader, etc.) then Chrome opens the in-page search box instead of invoking the shortcut action.

The same keyboard shortcuts work just fine on Firefox15 on the same Win7 computer.

I've looked in Chrome's settings (including the advanced settings) but I didn't see anything that looked relevant. I searched both [SU](https://superuser.com/search?q=tag:google-chrome%20keyboard%20shortcuts%20&submit=search) and [webapps.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=chrome%20keyboard%20shortcuts%20&submit=search) but found nothing. Ironically, [Google can't answer this either.](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why%20don%27t%20keyboard%20shortcuts%20work%20in%20Google%20Chrome%20browser?)

**How can I make Chrome send my keypresses to the webpage (Gmail etc.) rather than starting an on-page text search?**

Comment: You don't have find-as-you-type installed, do you?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Bingo! I checked, and there was one called "Type-ahead-find". I've disabled that and reloaded Gmail, now it works. But now I don't have type-ahead search anymore ;-p How does Firefox handle this? In Ffox, there's a standard setting "Search for text when I start typing" (not an extension) and that somehow automatically works on pages that don't have shortcuts, and leaves Gmail etc. alone.

Comment: It was actually just a suspicion. I have no real experience. Sorry :(

Comment: which keys in particular? They work fine here.

Comment: @Sathya: Oliver already solved the mystery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OliverSalzburg suggested that it might be a conflicting extension that "catches" my keypresses. I checked, and there was one called "Type-ahead-find".

I disabled that extension and my keyboard shortcuts work as they should again!

Comment: did not work for me (all extension removed)

Comment: Almost 10 years later... same issue, was driving me crazy. That was my issue too, I had that same extension installed! Fixed by blacklisting http*://mail.google.com/* in the extension's configuration.