# Shortcut keys in Google Sheet don't work?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-spreadsheets

Background:
I have version 45.0.2454.85 m of Chrome (the latest when writing this question). I have a Swedish version of Logitech MX 5500 physical wireless Bluetooth keyboard.

Problem:
My problem is regarding shortcut keys with Google (spread)Sheets and Chrome. For example, when pressing the following key combination, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, you are supposed to insert a date in the selected cell. When I do it (press the key combination), I get nothing. No date will be inserted (and no other key shortcuts works either).

The following answer, [Why don't keyboard shortcuts work in Google Chrome browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/485112/why-dont-keyboard-shortcuts-work-in-google-chrome-browser) suggests it's an issue with an extension ("Type-ahead-find") that conflicts with it, but I don't have this or any other obvious extensions either.

How can I resolve my problem with shortcut keys on Google Sheets?

Comment: The key combination is actually `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `;`. Is there a reason why yours is in reverse?

Comment: Does it work in any other browser on the same machine?

Comment: I have only IE 11 available (except Chrome). Can't get Google Sheet shortcuts to work in IE either. Does it work for you?

Comment: What keyboard language is your PC set to when typing? If you require an extra key to type in ";" that might be a problem.

Comment: Hmm... The keyboard settings is for Swedish laguage and I don't need any extra keys for typing a plain literal ";" in any spread sheet cell (I'm using Chrome and IE as browsers, it works in both of them).